# How to merge two sql select

Tags: sql, merge

I want to merge two SQL selects from one table

Query 1:

```
SELECT UserId
FROM ShoppingLike
WHERE (ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2) AND (WhichId = 75)
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT ShoppingLike.WhichId
FROM ShoppingLike
WHERE (ShoppingLike.ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2) AND (ShoppingLike.UserId = 189)
```

Instead of `75` in query 1 how should I use the result of query 2?

Comment: It might help if you supply sample data and expected results...

Comment: @sgeddes I'm guessing he wants a `UNION`...what else could it be?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen -- not really sure to be honest, `union` could make sense, but so could `exists` or `in`.  Who knows at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly with a sub-select query?

```
SELECT UserId
FROM ShoppingLike
WHERE WhichId IN (
    SELECT WhichId
    FROM ShoppingLike
    WHERE (ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2) AND (UserId = 189)
)
```

Although this would always produce rows with `UserId` 189 as the result, in which case the query could simply be written like this:

```
SELECT UserId
FROM ShoppingLike
WHERE (ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2) AND (UserId = 189)
```

This would return a row for each record with `ShoppingScoreTypeId` = 2 for `UserId` 189.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        UserId
FROM            ShoppingLike
WHERE        (ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2)
AND WhichId = (
 SELECT        top 1 ShoppingLike.WhichId
 FROM            ShoppingLike
 WHERE        (ShoppingLike.ShoppingScoreTypeId = 2) AND (ShoppingLike.UserId = 189)
)
```

Comment: why "SELECT        top 1 " , it must be array of record, not only one record

Comment: Oh, you asked to match the result of your second query. In that case remove "top 1" and change "and WhichId in (...)